# Detect maximize/minimize window event and do it programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

How detect Minimize/Maximize window and **do this programmatically**. I know that i need use `NSWindowdelegate`, but:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowdelegate {
    func windowWillMiniaturize(_ notification: Notification) {
            print("1")
        }
}
```

This not working. And how to maximize/minimize programmatically have no idea.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is all in Apples documentation on `NSWindowDelegate`: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindowdelegate

You can implement in you class that is set as delegate for your window:

```
func windowWillMiniaturize(Notification)
```

Tells the delegate that the window is about to be minimized.

```
func windowDidMiniaturize(Notification)
```

Tells the delegate that the window has been minimized.

```
func windowDidDeminiaturize(Notification)
```

Tells the delegate that the window has been deminimized.

NSWindow has methods - easily to find when visiting the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow

You can call from anywhere on your window:

```
func performMiniaturize(Any?)
```

Simulates the user clicking the minimize button by momentarily highlighting the button, then minimizing the window.

```
func miniaturize(Any?)
```

Removes the window from the screen list and displays the minimized window in the Dock.

```
func deminiaturize(Any?)
```

De-minimizes the window.